# How to make the preparation more efficient in database query using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

For example, I have a couple of tables in my database, e.g., user, product, etc. Fro every table, I have at least an associated class with a couple of methods, such as addUser, updateUserName, updateUserPassword, etc. For every method, I need to prepare the SQL when using PDO, which looks like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user`
(`id`,`username`,`password`,`log`)
VALUES
(:id, :username, :password, :log)";
```

Then I store the values in an array like this:

```
$array = array('id'=>$id, 'username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password, 'log'=>$log);
```

Then I use the PDO thing:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$mysql = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$mysql->execute($array);
```

So it seems that for all different methods inside the User class, I need to do this "prepare" thing. Isn't it too tedious? Is there a more efficient way to do so, especially the part where I store the values in an array considering there exist a table with many columns in which case I would end up with a very long prepare sentence?

Comment: im confused as to why you would need this for *every* method and not just once

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "just one." If different methods have different array to be prepared, and not necessarily all the function parameters needs to be prepared in the array, for example when query using LIMIT $offset, $page_size, these two parameters don't need to be prepared. How would I prepare the values once then?

Comment: Are you well equipped in OOP, if yes then I think a single DB class could help

Comment: well the question said every method same insert, now its different - so

Comment: I understand the concept of OOP, but I am not fully aware of what exactly to do inside the DB class. Could you explain it in more detail? Thanks.

Comment: I created some sort of custom DB class for my project if you insist I can send it to you here

Comment: @GideonAppoh, that would be very helpful!

Comment: ok i no longer see a problem, you have to write code to do stuff- thats the nature of programming - perhaps you could write less code - but thats not always a good thing

Comment: @Dagon, are you saying what I am doing currently is a common practice? Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Since Your own is insert and update try these

```
        //to query the database with prepared statements
    public function query ($sql, $parameters = array()) {

        //setting error to false to prevent interferance from previous failed queries
        $this->_error = false;

        //prepare SQL statement
        if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare ($sql)) {

            //checking to see whether any parameters were submitted along
            if (count($parameters)) {

                //setting the initial position for the binding values
                $position = 1;

                //getting the individual parameters and binding them with their respective fields
                foreach ($parameters as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue ($position, $param);
                    $position++;
                }
            }
        }

        //executing the sql
        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            //getting the number of rows returned
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();

            //keeping the results returned
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
        //returning all values of $this
        return $this;
    }


        //to insert data into a prescribed table
    public function insert ($table, $parameters = array()) {

        //checking if the $fields are not empty
        if (count($parameters)) {

            //making the keys of the array fields
            $fields = array_keys ($parameters);

            //creating the to-bind-values in the form (?, ?, ...)
            $values = '';
            $x = 1;

            foreach ($parameters as $field => $value) {

                //$value is different from $values
                $values .= '?';

                if ($x < count($parameters)) {
                    $values .= ', ';
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            //generating $sql
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (`".implode ('`, `', $fields)."`) VALUES ({$values})";

            //executing the sql
            if (!$this->query($sql, $parameters)->error()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //to update data in a prescribed table
    public function update ($table, $id = null, $parameters = array()) {

        //checking that $parameters is not an empty array
        if (count($parameters)) {
            $set = '';
            $x = 1;

            foreach ($parameters as $field => $value) {
                $set .= "`{$field}` = ?";

                if ($x < count($parameters)) {
                    $set .= ', ';
                    $x++;
                }
            }

            if ($id) {
                //generating query
                $sql = "UPDATE `{$table}` SET {$set} WHERE `id` = {$id}";
            } else {
                $sql = "UPDATE `{$table}` SET {$set} WHERE 1";
            }

            //executing the query
            if (!$this->query($sql, $parameters)->error()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: he is using prepared statements, your not

Comment: its hash to down vote someone if you don't really take time to read his/her answer, that's not cool at all

Comment: nice try buddy, i can see the edit history, you completely changed the answer

Comment: I was on editing when you voted the answer down and even didn't you realize the sql was calling a function called query

Comment: @GideonAppoh, thanks for the code. Is this a more efficient way or will it actually harm the query efficiency (not coding time)?

Comment: @Dainy, as I said this is a custom DB class I used for a certain project, and for you to use it I think it depends on you.